# Accessing variables in gameobjects inside of an array from another script

Tags: c#

I created an array (inside a script named OverallDisplay) of five gameobjects.

Each one of these objects have a script named CardDisplay, that holds a int value named overall.

I'd like to, inside of the OverallDisplay script, get all of these five ints, named overall, sum them all together and divide by five.

As I said, I already made an array of gameobjects and selected the five objects inside the inspector, but I just cant access these int values of each gameobject to sum them up.

If I make five references, then I can do it, but I`d like to keep the array instead of making five different references.

How could I do it in c#?

This is the code CardDisplay, that all five gameobjects in the array have.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CardDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{

public PlayerCard card;

public Text nameText;
public Text descriptionTex;

public Image artworkCharacter;

public Text shootText;
public Text fightText;
public Text visionTex;

public int overall;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    nameText.text = card.playerName;
    descriptionTex.text = card.description;

    artworkCharacter.sprite = card.artwork;

    shootText.text = card.shoot.ToString();
    fightText.text = card.fight.ToString();
    visionTex.text = card.vision.ToString();
    overall = (card.shoot + card.fight + card.vision) / 3;
    
}

void    Update()
{
}

}
```

This is the code I'm using to get the gameobjects that holds the CardDisplay script and putting them inside an array. To do this, I tagged these objects as FirstLine inside the inspector.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class OverallDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject[] usedCards;
public int teamOverall;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    usedCards = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("FirstLine");
}
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you show us your code

Comment: I added, sorry about that!